# How to remove more than one container in a single command?

Tags: docker, containers

How can I remove more than one container in a single command?
I have some containers which I want to remove: `mynginx2` and `mynginx1`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use the remove command with comma

**docker container rm mynginx2,  mynginx1**

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command:

```
docker rm mynginx2 mynginx1
```

---

```
Usage:  docker rm [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [CONTAINER...]

Remove one or more containers

Options:
  -f, --force     Force the removal of a running container (uses SIGKILL)
      --help      Print usage
  -l, --link      Remove the specified link
  -v, --volumes   Remove anonymous volumes associated with the container
```

Reference:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/